# Store Services crash for ios 11

Tags: ios, ios11, admob

My app is causing crash in crashlytics for ios 11 devices only . This seems to be occurring for many people ( [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/34637890) and [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87724) ). Anyone found a fix for it ? Below is the description of the crash.

---

**
Crashed: com.apple.StoreServices.SSRequest.0x1c0ac8810

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x185348430 objc_msgSend + 16

1  StoreServices                  0x190b281b4 -[SSRequest _shutdownRequestWithMessageID:] + 228

2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857a5088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857a5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16

4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857aee48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528

5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857af7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340

6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857b0200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400

7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1857b84a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644

8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185a4afe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932

9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185a4ac30 start_wqthread + 4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed here in the release notes

`7.24.1   2017‑9‑27 Updates the way the SDK interacts with Apple's StoreServices.`

Listed here https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes

Comment: The crash still happens after upgraded to 7.24.1

Comment: @PrimaryChicken can you tell please didi you find solution?